# Change color of points and interpolation line of ListPlot

Tags: plotting

I ploted an interpolation line along with data points:

```
dark = {{0.1592, 0}, {0.5995, 1}, {0.6968, 2}, {0.7554, 3}, {0.8007, 4}, {0.8377, 5}, {0.8692, 6}, {0.899, 7}, {0.9246, 8}, {0.9487, 9}, {0.9716, 10}, {0.9921, 11}, {1.0129, 12}, {1.0317, 13}, {1.0497,14}, {1.0671, 15}, {1.0834, 16}, {1.1009, 17}, {1.1179, 18}, {1.1347, 19}, {1.15, 20}}
ListPlot[{dark, dark}, Joined -> {False, True}, InterpolationOrder -> 3, PlotRange -> All]
```

It gave this polt:

[image: plot of data]

Now I want to change the points' color to one color and the interpolation line's color to another one. I can do this using drawing tools. But how to do this by typing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dark = {{0.1592, 0}, {0.5995, 1}, {0.6968, 2}, {0.7554, 3}, {0.8007, 
   4}, {0.8377, 5}, {0.8692, 6}, {0.899, 7}, {0.9246, 8}, {0.9487, 
   9}, {0.9716, 10}, {0.9921, 11}, {1.0129, 12}, {1.0317, 
   13}, {1.0497, 14}, {1.0671, 15}, {1.0834, 16}, {1.1009, 
   17}, {1.1179, 18}, {1.1347, 19}, {1.15, 20}}
ListLinePlot[dark, PlotStyle -> Green, Mesh -> Full, MeshStyle -> Red,
  InterpolationOrder -> 3, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: This is the canonical method.